# How does ORMLite store ForeignCollections in the database?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have two classes, User and Artwork. User can have a collection of Artworks. Everything works as expected, I can store and retrieve the objects from the db, but I don,t understand how they collection is persisted.

```java
public class User {

    @DatabaseField(allowGeneratedIdInsert = true, generatedId = true, unique = true)
    Long id;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "artwork_id", foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    Artwork masterPiece;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    Collection<Artwork> artworks;
} 

public class Artwork {

    @DatabaseField(allowGeneratedIdInsert = true, generatedId = true, unique = true)
    Long id;

    @DatabaseField
    String name;

    @DatabaseField
    String file;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "user_id", foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    User owner;
}
```

I create some artworks, add them to the collection and set the collection in the a User. When checking the .db (.schema) I get this:

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR , `artwork_id` BIGINT );
CREATE TABLE `artwork` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR , `file` VARCHAR , `user_id` BIGINT );
```

Objects are being correctly inserted and querying for them works like charm. What I really don't understand is why I there is no field for the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User** and **Artwork** entities has **one-to-many** relationship.  In relational databases this is modeled as `Artwork` having a column which references `User` (`user_id`, in this case). To get collection of `Artwork` associated with `User` (id), ormlite executes query which roughly looks like:

`select * from Artwork where user_id = id`

- More info about [ormlite foreign collection support](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection)
- [Database relationships](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)